# Cant Make more than 1 insert without refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

So I have a very basic app that is using the MEAN stack. I am submitting form data and inserting into mongoLab via node but for some reason I cannot send two batches of data without a refresh. If I try to send two different batches of data I get a duplicate key error `MongoError: insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error`

I am rather new to this so I am not sure what is going on. I know that Mongo does not allow two of the same fields to be null but all of the data is changing and accounted for on submit. Here is my code:

**Angular**

```
app.controller('HistoryController', function($scope, $filter, $http){
    $scope.usersHistories = masterHistory;
    $scope.users = users;
    $scope.formatDate = function(date, format) {
        return $filter('date')(date, format);
    };

    $http.get('/api/history').
        success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            //var masterHistory = data.toJSON();
            console.log(data);
        //  masterHistory.push(data);
        });

/*  function appendToBSheet (block) {
        masterHistory.push(
        {
            transDate: block.date,
            directObject: block.user,
            transAmount: block.cost,
            transType: block.type,
            transLocale: block.location
        }
    );
    }*/

    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.submit = function(){
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/api/transactions',
            data: $.param($scope.formData),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        })
            .success(function(newTrans, status, headers, config){
                console.log(newTrans);
                //if(!newTrans.success) {
                //  $scope.errorName = newTrans.errors.name;
                //  $scope.errorLocation= newTrans.errors.location;
                //} else {
                    $scope.message = newTrans.message;
                //appendToBSheet(newTrans);
                $("form").trigger("reset");

                //}
            });
    };      
});
```

**Node API**

```
app.post('/api/transactions', parseUrlencoded, function(req, res){
...
  var transaction = {   };
var date = new Date();
var dd = date.getDate();
var mm = date.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0
var yy = date.getFullYear();

if (dd<10) {
    dd = "0" + dd;
}

if (mm<10) {
    mm = "0" + mm;
}

var HH = date.getHours();
var MM = date.getMinutes();
var timeHalf;


if (HH > 12) {
    timeHalf = "pm";
    HH = HH - 12;
} else {
    timeHalf = "am";
}

if (MM < 10) {
    MM = "0" + MM;
} else {
    MM=MM;
}

  date = yy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;
  time = HH + ":" + MM + timeHalf;

  var newTrans = req.body;
  transaction["transDate"] = date
  transaction["transTime"] = time;  
  transaction["directObject"] = newTrans.name;
  transaction["transAmount"] = newTrans.cost;
  transaction["transType"] = "credit";
  transaction["transLocale"] = newTrans.location;    
  transaction["UserID"] = 2;


  var transColl = db.collection("transactions");
```

**Edit**

```
  transColl.insert(transaction, function(err, result){
    if (err) throw err;
    res.status(200).json(result); //sending result after insert

  });

console.log(newTrans);
```

**SCHEMA**

```
{
"_id": "id",
"Date": "transDate",
"Time": "transTime",
"Recipient": "directObject",
"Type": "transType",
"Location": "transLocale",
"Verifier": "UserID"
}
```

Comment: It might have something to do with you not returning any response. I've had issues with node hanging when the api fails and doesnt hit the response. Try adding a res.json({message: 'success'}) or something in your api

Comment: Your code doesn't show how `date` and `time` get populated.  Can you add that code in case it might be relevant?

Comment: Date and time are above.

Comment: @ribsies I have a response sent with the data is also being sent to my db, I just didn't include it because I didn't think it was relevant. I have included it above

Comment: Could you show the code for the entire angular controller?  Maybe something isn't getting reset to a new value before you make the call a second time?

Comment: Try sending a response back when the insert succeeds. Right now you are sending it back before it is done since it is outside that async function

Comment: @ribsies changed the response so that it sends in the async function. same error :/

Comment: @NicholasSmith Updated the angular. the entire controller is now there.

Answer (score 0):

I would need to see your model Schema for your mongo table, but here could be your issue:

```
transaction["UserID"] = 2;
```

Since you are hard coding a db value that is supposed to be unique it causes a duplicate key issue.

Please post your model definitions for your mongo tables so I can elaborate

Edit: also please post the **req.body** values

Comment: `newTrans = req.body` output: "`{ name: 'Jake', location: 'Jasons', cost: '5' }`" As of the moment, that UserID field is **not** unique. It is still something I am working on but the only truly unique field is the `_id` generated by mongo.

Comment: Try removing UserID altogether to test

Comment: Very strange man. Kind of baffled myself. I would have to sit down and hash it out. Would also need to see all the code involved

Comment: Only thing else I can say is start eliminating keys until you get a successful result. Are you able to insert docs into the transaction table via the mongo shell?